# AngularJS - Upload Image to SharePoint Library/Corrupted File

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I am using the following Angular Module to attempt to upload images to SharePoint through a Web browser: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

I am getting successful 200 POST messages and a file is being uploaded... However, it is not showing the image itself in the preview or opening of the image, but rather an [X]. I am guessing this is related to how the content is encoded, but unsure of what to do next. Here is my controller:

```
appControllers.controller('appUploadImageCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'FileUploader', function ($scope, $location, FileUploader) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: "/sites/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Images')/RootFolder/Files/add(url='test.jpg',overwrite='true')",
        processData: false,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': undefined, 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() }
    });

    // FILTERS

    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'imageFilter',
        fn: function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
            return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
        }
    });

    // CALLBACKS

    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter,

    options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function (addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
    };
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    };
    uploader.onProgressItem = function (fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
    };
    uploader.onProgressAll = function (progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
    };
    uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onErrorItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCancelItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function () {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
    };

    console.info('uploader', uploader);

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>Select files</h3>
            <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                <!-- 3. nv-file-over uploader="link" over-class="className" -->
                <div class="well my-drop-zone" nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader">
                    Base drop zone
                </div>
                <!-- Example: nv-file-drop="" uploader="{Object}" options="{Object}" filters="{String}" -->
                <div nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" options="{ url: '/foo' }">
                    <div nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader" over-class="another-file-over-class" class="well my-drop-zone">
                        Another drop zone with its own settings
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Example: nv-file-select="" uploader="{Object}" options="{Object}" filters="{String}" -->
            Multiple
            <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple /><br />
            Single
            <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">
            <h3>Upload queue</h3>
            <p>Queue length: {{ uploader.queue.length }}</p>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50%">Name</th>
                        <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Size</th>
                        <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Progress</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                        <td><strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong></td>
                        <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                        <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                            <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                            <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                            <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <div>
                    Queue progress:
                    <div class="progress" style="">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s" ng-click="uploader.cancelAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.isUploading">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" ng-click="uploader.clearQueue()" ng-disabled="!uploader.queue.length">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to upload your image as a normal `byte array`, which isn't possible when you are uploading to libraries through the SharePoint REST API.

To be able to upload non-text files to SharePoint, they have to be uploaded as a `base64` encoded byte array.

Your options are to either use another Angular module such as [Angular-Base64-Upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload), or to encode the image file before you upload it using your first choice of file upload module.

In case you go for option two, you can encode the image using the following technique, though how it will work with your selected file uploader, I cannot say. It appears you can modify the `file` attribute of the `FileItem` in the file uploader, so it should not be that hard.

**Encoding the image file to a base64 binary arraybuffer**

```
//Create a new FileReader object
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = processImage;

//Read the file as a base64 encoded string
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

function processImage () {
    //The image file has been read by the filereader
    //and can be converted to an arraybuffer
    var arrayBuffer = base64ToBinary(this.result);

    //Upload the image to the SharePoint images library
    uploadImage(arrayBuffer);
}

function base64ToBinary (base64EncodedFile) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = base64EncodedFile.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = base64EncodedFile.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array.buffer;
}
```

When I wrote a similar piece of code for a project, I noticed that SharePoint (or just IE) had trouble getting the MIME types correct. I ended up stripping it from the image to make it work, as below.

```
var raw = atob(base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
```

---

**Uploading to SharePoint image library using the REST API and Ajax**

If you decide to not go for an Angular module to upload your file, you can instead upload files directly to a SharePoint library through the REST API using normal ajax calls with jQUery. This might have to be modified for the Angular syntax, but the concept is the same.

```
var requestUrl = String.format("{0}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Images')/rootfolder/files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)", _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, fileName);

$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: buffer, //This is the base64 encoded buffer from the above step
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("Upload complete!");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
});
```

Comment: If I don't use the file uploaded module, what is the "normal"/simple method for uploading images using base64 over REST? I need to use SP's REST API as JSOM is limited to uploads of 1.5 MB

Comment: I've updated my answer to inlcude how you can upload to the image library using jQuery and simple ajax!

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate the explanation and will test it ASAP

Comment: Have you had any success with your problem? If so, and you found my answer helpful, consider marking it as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: No yet, got pulled in another direction. Back in a week, and will test/reach out if resolved to close the question

Comment: I'm back and looking closely at your option where you encode the file, but when I try to use data: buffer it fails as buffer is not defined. Should array.buffer be buffer in your return statement?